# Can I use Skype Web SDK to build a IM Chat Bot for Skype for Business/Skype?

Tags: azure, skype, botframework, chatbot, skype-for-business

I need to be able to initiate a connection from the bot to a SfB user. The bot will be making the connection as a published Web App on Azure.

The bot can have its own SfB id and will message people from there.

If it can be achieved for Skype instead of SfB, I'd still like to know how I would go about implementing a solution for that.

Comment: SfB = Skype for Business

Answer (score 0):

The Bot term here is misleading me a bit, but from the scenario you mentioned, it sounds like a chat between a Web App using the Skype Web SDK and an SfB client. As long as the Web App is using a SfB creds, that should be possible.

Comment: Can you please explain this a little bit more ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SfB with bot framework right at the moment. But you can use skype instead. To create a bot which work with the skype please follow the below steps.

1. First register a new bot inside the bot framework. [Click here](https://dev.botframework.com/). Keep in mind that you need Microsoft account for that.(outlook, live)
2. Then download bot application template from [here](http://aka.ms/bf-bc-vstemplate). Save the zip file to your Visual Studio 2015 templates directory which is traditionally in `“%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#"`
3. After that you can download bot emulator to check your bot from [here](https://aka.ms/bf-bc-emulator)
4. Add your AppId and AppSecret (You can find that from the bot registration dash board) inside web config file. Then run your application and check whether you get the same wording you send through the emulator.
5. If all are working you can connect it to the skype like this. First go to dashboard in web. Enable skype and there you can find few steps to follow. If you success with that steps you can see your bot inside your skype where you can communicate. *For publish to public crowd it takes time and your bot go through a quality process which handle by Microsoft.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

FYI - Skype for Business was announced as a new channel today on Build 2017 :)